# Removing ".0" from version numbers

Tags: php, string, statistics, version

I am developing a runtime intelligence software program. It collects the version number of programs so you can then see the statistics for each version number. The problem I am having with this is that some computers are sending the actual version number (ie: 0.4) and others are sending an erroneous version number (ie: 0.4.0). I was wondering if it would be OK if I used something like:

```
$version = rtrim($version, ".0");
```

Would this work to get rid of this problem or what this just cause more problems later on down the road?

Comment: The last segment of `0.4.0` is not erroneous. There is a difference between versions `0.4.0` and `0.4.1`.

Comment: and so is version 1.0.0 the zeroes are there for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This absolutely can cause problems. `rtrim` strips those characters if they appear at the end of the string in any order and possibly multiple times. So `1.10`  will become `1.1` but these are not necessarily the same version.

See it online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/2557G)

Comment: More importantly 10.01 will become 101

Comment: Thanks. I am now using substr() instead of rtrim() to remove a trailing '.0' like this:

        `if ( substr_count( $sAppVer, '.' ) > 1 ) {
            // Remove trailing '.0' so '1.0.0' turns into '1.0'
            if ( substr( $sAppVer, -2 ) == '.0' ) 
                $sAppVer = substr( $sAppVer, 0, -2 );
        }`

Answer (score 0):

And what do you do if there is a "actual version" number, how you call it, of say, 5.0 ?

I suggest you use a regex instead, probably the preg_match() function:

```
$tokens=preg_match($version,'/^([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/',$tokens);
if (3=count($tokens))
     $actualVersion=sprintf('%s.%s',$tokens[1],$tokens[2]);
else $actualVersion=='?.?';
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on *Mark Byers*' answer, you can't use `rtrim()`.

I recommend `preg_replace()`:

```
$ver = '0.4.0';
$pattern = '/^([0-9.]+)\.0$/';
$replacement = '${1}';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $ver);
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/upmfD)